# Cannot install MahApps assembly using IronPython in Visual Studio (with PTVS 2.0)

Tags: wpf, nuget, ironpython, mahapps.metro, ptvs

I am trying to create a MahApps styled WPF application using IronPython 2.7.3 in Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 with PTVS. However I cannot install MahApps.Metro via Nuget using the GUI. Choosing 'Install' in the Manage NuGet Packages console trows the following error by Visual Studio:

> 'MahApps.Metro' could not be installed because it is not compatible with any project in the solution. The package targets the following frameworks:
>
> .NetFramwork, Verion=v4.0
>
> .NetFramwork, Verion=v4.5

Trying out the other packages from MahApps (MahApps.Metro.Recources (and .StanAlone)) both trough an error as well:

> 'MahApps.Metro.Recources' could not be installed because it is not compatible with any project in the solution. The package doesn't target any framework.

I have created a new IronPython WPF application using both the .NET 4.0 and 4.5 Framework. In the documentation on MahApps I cannot find anything resembling an exclusion of certain languages even though it seems IronPython is not supported.

**Any suggestions into how I could install mahapps.metro assemblies in an IronPython WPF application either using NuGet or an alternative way would be greatly appreciated.**

*FYI: I made a C# WPF application using the same frameworks. Here I can install the MahApss assemblies as I should and they work perfectly fine there.*

Comment: Have you been able to install other .NET packages into an IronPython WPF application - like Newtonsoft.Json for example? Could this be a NuGet limitation?

Comment: Thanks Brendan. I tried installing Newtonsoft.Json trough the Manage NuGet Packages and lo and behold:  _'Newtonsoft.Json' could not be installed because it is not compatible with anay projects in the solution. The package targets the following frameworks: .NetFramework,Version=v2.0 .NetFramework,Version=v3.5 .NetFramework,Version=v4.0 .NetFramework,Version=v4.5 .NetCore,Version=v4.5_ I'm starting to fear that Visual Studio (or PTVS) doesn't acknowledge my installed .NetFrameworks at all. Is there a way to check this?

Comment: It's probably a PTVS issues; their project support is fairly new. Your best bet is to open an issue with them (https://pytools.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Jeff for the Response. I have posted the same question on pytools.codeplex.com and I was able to find a work-around solution for this problem. Check: https://pytools.codeplex.com/workitem/1212 for a detailed work-around strategy.